# How to access vuex store from fetch or asyncData hook in NuxtJS?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I want to access vuex store specifically getters from fetch hook.

Here is my getters I'm loading using mapGetters inside order page

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters("auth", ["authUser"])
  },
```

Here is apollo call from fetch hook and I'm trying to provide **authUser.id** as a variable which is provided by **authUser** getter from vuex store.

```
async fetch() {
    console.log("fetch order is called");
    const orderInput = {
      userId: this.authUser.id,
      orderStatus: "PENDING"
    };

    const response = await this.$apollo.query({
      query: getOrdersByUserIdQuery,
      variables: { orderInput }
    });

    this.orders = response.data.getOrderByUserId.orders;
    console.log("getOrderResponse", response);
  },
```

But, it fails to load the **authUser** from the store in initial page load.

I am curious to know If my steps are correct or not. If this is not correct what are the other alternatives that can I follow?

Comment: why isn't this a single array? `...mapGetters(["auth","authUser"])`

Comment: also you will need to show where you are triggering the event which sets the `authUser` in your store.

Comment: @kiddorails authUser is an object that is saved after successful user login. It is not an array, it is an object already available in auth module of the vuex store

Comment: got it. I was unaware about namespace concept. Just read.

Comment: @kiddorails Thanks a lot. Sorry for my misunderstanding. Do you have any solution regarding my question? I am stuck at a stage for this issue.

Comment: Hi. I would like to see how you are dispatching the event which sets the authUser. It's probable that it's not happening by the time you request `fetch`

Answer (score 2):

use this.$store for (Nuxt >= 2.12).
you should already have a store :)

Answer (score 1):

If your Nuxt version is >= 2.12

maybe you can try to use anonymous middleware to get context

like this:

```
async middleware({ store }) {
    await store.dispatch('one/fetchSomething')
  },
```

In document `https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/` says:

*fetch(context) has been deprecated, instead you can use an anonymous middleware in your page: middleware(context)*